# Exporting Postgres data without pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

My company 'upgraded' their postgres servers to version 12 but have not updated the client tools beyond version 10 so I cant pg_dump export to backup my prod data to do a monthly prod to beta re-sync.  Is there a safe way to run selects and output the file in a way I can do an insert into the other db.  I am concerned with delimiters screwing up the insert mostly.

Yes I am trying to get my company to package the right tools but this has been going on way too long

Comment: How did they upgrade that did not include pg_dump? Can you access the 12 server from a machine that does have 12 client programs?

Comment: Not so much as a upgrade as a new service that is more like a hosted postgress rather than bare metal.   I only have access to psql from version 10 and a windows based PGAmin but it runs under a windows RDP 'VM'.  And I dont have access to the mounts so I cant run a 'backup'. Yes they need to fix this, we ended up being new users to a new service and are suffering a bit in short term.

Comment: Postgresql is server/client, if you can reach the server from another machine then can dump it from that machine. This is along as you have Postgresql 12 programs on the machine. Personally I would run not walk away from this 'service'. A setup that does not include backup in it's package is dangerous.